# Cloud Run:<Cloud SQL instance IP adress> :3306: connect: connection timed out

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I want to connect Cloud SQL in Cloud Run Application. I used golang. this is the code around sql connect setting.

```golang
func getEnv(key, def string) string {
    v := os.Getenv(key)
    if v == "" {
        return def
    }
    return v
}
```

```golang
        DB: DB{
            User:     getEnv("DB_USER", "<user name>"),
            Pass:     getEnv("DB_PASS", "<password>"),
            Host:     getEnv("DB_HOST", "0.0.0.0"),
            Port:     getEnv("DB_PORT", "3306"),
            Database: getEnv("DB_DATABASE", "<database name>"),
        },
```

```golang
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?charset=utf8&parseTime=true",
        config.DB.User, config.DB.Pass, config.DB.Host, config.DB.Port, config.DB.Database)

    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", dsn)
```

I set environment variable at Cloud Run setting console. After delpoy Application, Cloud Run console display `Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.` and `dial tcp <Cloud SQL Private IP> :3306: connect: connection timed out` I wonder SQL connection is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned the word "VPC" in your question so I'm assuming you don't use it.

Cloud Run cannot directly connect to a private IP of a Cloud SQL instance. You need to [configure a Serverless VPC Access Connector](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc) and specify it while deploying your Cloud Run app.

Cloud Run containers are not part of a VPC by default, so unless you do this, they will not have access to the private networks.

Comment: I didn't configure Serverless VPC Access Connector. After I created it and set Cloud Run, program was sloved. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is several way to connect your Cloud SQL database to Cloud Run. If it's MySQL, the easiest way is to follow the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run)

If you want to use the IP with TCP connection, firstly, you can't use 0.0.0.0 as IP.

- Use the Cloud SQL public IP (for this you have to authorize 0.0.0.0/0 network range on your Cloud SQL instance, and it's absolutely not recommended)
- Plug your [Cloud SQL to your VPC](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip). And, as described by Ahmet, use serverless VPC connector to link Cloud Run with your VPC. Then add the private IP of your Cloud SQL in your code.